# two stage op amp's PSRR

Tags: operational-amplifier, fet

[image]

I recently study about two stage amp.

In Sedra-Smith, it stays that PSRR for VDD is very small, and ignores this.

To understand this, I set Q6's source Vin and Q6 is acting like a common gate amplifier.

So $$\text{Gain} =  g_{m6}(r_{o6} \parallel r_{o7})$$

I thought like this first. It doesn't make sense.

So next, I set like this; Q7's drain and gate are connected, Q7 acts like diode-connected FET which has resistance \$1/g_m\$, so gain has to be rewrite as $$g_{m6}[r_{o6} \parallel (1/g_{m7})]$$

But this does not make sense too, because the gain is 1. What am I missing?

- And I cannot understand this too,
  [image]

If ground is replaced as VSS, that denotes the Vout caused of VSS.

How it would be voltage divided form? That formula means that Q7 is diode-connected which has resistance \$r_{o7}\$, I cannot handle with this.

Comment: Have you drawn and looked at the **small signal equivalent model** of this circuit? *That formula means that Q7 is diode-connected* Explain why you think that. If Q7 was a MOS-diode then there would be a \$gm_7\$ in the expression, there isn't. Also \$1/gm\$ is generally much smaller than \$r_o\$ so then the PSRR would be quite large. But again, do a proper **small signal analysis** and instead of diving into formulas, ask yourself "what happens". When I use that approach I can "easily" see that the PSRR is like a voltage divider behavior.

Comment: Oh, I got that. I should consider the first stage's function.

Comment: I had a mistake. I have to open capacitors while deriving DC gain transfer function.

For Vdd, due to current mirror action from reference stage, Vov keeps the same value. That means v_gs isn't change.
So I can ignore the amplifing effect of gm6, just get a volt divide form of ro6, ro7.
For Vss, first stage's Vout is approximately same as Vss, so we can ignore gm7 at the same way of upper logic, just getting volt devide form of ro6, ro7.

Because Q6 is current source, which means that ro6 is very large, ripple due to Vdd is very small, though ripple from Vss doesn't, Right?